# show alert bootstrap when mail sended without new page

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

I would like to display an alert after sending an email as in this portfolio: https://www.mathieu-crevoulin.com/ after when you send mail you can see this alert :  E-mail envoyé avec succès !
Merci pour votre message !
Une réponse vous sera apportée dans les plus brefs délais.

contact.php

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST["send"])){

    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'mymail@mail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'psw';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port = 465;      
    $mail->setFrom('mymail@mail.com');

    $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Projet web';
    $mail->Body = "Message:" . $body . "<br>Phone number: " . $phone . "<br>Name: " . $name . "<br>Mail: " . $email;

    $mail->send();

    header("Location:  http://127.0.0.1/test2/confirmmail.html#scrollspyHeading7");
   

    
}
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha512-doJrC/ocU8VGVRx3O9981+2aYUn3fuWVWvqLi1U+tA2MWVzsw+NVKq1PrENF03M+TYBP92PnYUlXFH1ZW0FpLw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1aca141b14.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
    #success-message, #error-message
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom" style="padding: 1%;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Avatar Logo" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Compétences</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Portfolio</a>
                    </li> -->

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">À Propos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- images/114-1144561_copyright-free-images-on-desk-with-laptop-and.jpg
    images/269-2698560_high-resolution-laptop-desktop-wallpaper-hd.jpg
    images/10705380.jpg -->


    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -40%" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example bg-light rounded-2" tabindex="0">

        <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" id="scrollspyHeading1">
                <div class="carousel-item active " data-bs-interval="3000">
                    <img src="images/888777555.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">

                    <div class="carousel-caption  d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100" style="top: 0">
                        <h2 class="in-left">Développeur indépendant</h2>
                        <p class="in-left">SAVINOV Denis</p>
                    </div>


                </div>
    
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <h5 class="text-end"><strong>Intégration Web</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-end grisclaire">Des intégrations (X)HTML / CSS respectueuses des
                                    standards du Web.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <h5 class="text-end"><strong>Développements spécifiques</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-end grisclaire">Des outils adaptés à votre coeur de métier,
                                    applications & solutions personnalisées.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <h5 class="text-end"><strong>Référencement naturel</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-end grisclaire">Affichage sémantique des informations,
                                    des pages propres pour un référencement optimal.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-right">
                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons" style="width: 100%;"><img class="img-fluid w-100" src="images/5902216.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0 row align-items-center">
                        <div class="row align-items-center" data-aos="fade-up">
                            <div class="col">
                                <img src="images/index1.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 d-none d-lg-block" alt="...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">

                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons" style="width: 100%;"><img src="images/kisspng-icon-design-web-development-responsive-web-design-black-brush-5afd4d493dd9d2.7237427015265498332534.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <h5 class="text-start"><strong>Conception graphique & Webdesign</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-start grisclaire">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires,
                                    cartes de visite, newsletters...</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons" style="width: 100%;"><img src="images/3938579.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <h5 class="text-start"><strong>Dynamisme des pages</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-start grisclaire">Des animations de contenu non intrusives
                                    pour embellir votre projet.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons" style="width: 100%;"><img src="images/2739572-200.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <h5 class="text-start"><strong>Interface d'administration</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-start grisclaire">Outils spécifiques au bon fonctionnement
                                    de votre entreprise.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons" style="width: 100%;"><img src="images/1027666.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10 footertext" data-aos="fade-left">
                                <h5 class="text-start"><strong>Responsive design</strong></h5>
                                <p class="text-start grisclaire">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application
                                    mobile.</p>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="imagesjolie">
            <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
        background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
        ),
        url(1393785.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="header-content">
                        <h1 class="text-center imagebluranimation" style="color: white;">Développement Web Responsive
                        </h1>
                        <h4 class="text-center imagebluranimation" style="color: white;">Compatible Mobile, Tablettes &
                            P.C</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="imagesjolie">
            <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
        background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
        ),
        url(521120.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="header-content">

                        <h1 class="text-center imagebluranimation" style="color: white;"> PME, associations ou
                            particuliers,
                            je réponds à vos besoins en développement web </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br>


        <div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading6" style="padding-bottom: 3%;">
            <h1 style="padding-top: 4%;" data-aos="fade-down">
                <g>À PROPOS</g>
            </h1>
            <h4 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);" data-aos="fade-down">Je suis développeur web freelance et j'aime ça !
            </h4>
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h4 class="text-start">Un développeur web passionné !</h4>
                    <p class="text-start grisclaire">Ma passion pour le développement web commence en 2003 et m'a
                        demandé un
                        changement
                        radical de cursus
                        afin de pouvoir pleinement l'exploiter.</br> </br>

                        Dès lors, je mis tout en oeuvre pour percer dans cette voie, tout en prenant du plaisir sur les
                        divers projets développés.</br> </br>

                        En Mai 2009, je décide de devenir développeur web indépendant après plusieurs postes en tant que
                        développeur web « full-stack » réussis, qui me conforteront dans cette idée afin de toucher un
                        plus
                        large panel de domaines d'activités, voir du pays et conquérir le monde !</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0 row align-items-center" data-aos="fade-up">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col">
                            <img src="images/index1.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 d-none d-lg-block" alt="...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0" data-aos="fade-left">

                    <h4 class="text-start">Expérience en développement</h4>

                    <p class="text-start grisclaire"> Mon expérience acquise au fil des projets me permet de mieux
                        comprendre les
                        attentes d'un client
                        et de
                        répondre précisement au besoin demandé en fonction du domaine d'activité.</p>

                    <p class="text-start grisclaire">Du site vitrine au projet plus complexe, je vous propose une
                        expertise et un
                        développement web qui
                        correspond à vos attentes & à vos besoins.</p>

                    <h3 class="text-start">Un tarif adapté à votre projet</h3>

                    <p class="text-start grisclaire"> Travaillant régulièrement avec des PME, associations ou
                        particuliers, je vous
                        propose des solutions
                        à
                        votre portée & adaptée à votre budget.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imagesjolie">
            <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
            background: linear-gradient(
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
            ),
            url(1393769.jpg);
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="header-content">
                        <h1 class="text-center imagebluranimation" style="color: white;"> Un interlocuteur unique pour
                            un site internet
                            réussi
                            !
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading7">
            <h1 style="padding-top: 4%;" data-aos="fade-down">
                <b>CONTACTEZ-MOI</b>
            </h1>
            <h3 class="footertext" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);padding: 1%;" data-aos="fade-down"><b>Une
                    idée ? Un projet ? N'hésitez pas à
                    demander un devis !
                    [GRATUIT]</b></h3>

            <div class="row align-items-center" style="padding: 3%;">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0 text-start">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-right">

                                <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-geo-alt-fill w-100"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10" style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3px;  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                                    <h6><b>ADRESSE</b></h6>
                                    <p>45, allée des Grives 83390 Cuers</p>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-whatsapp"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10" style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3px;  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                                    <h6><b>Téléphone</b></h6>
                                    <p>(+33) 6.15.42.10.45</p>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10" style="padding-top: 3%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                                    <h6><b>E-mail</b></h6>
                                    <p>contact@mcrevoulin.com</p>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d84484.16954510748!2d7.692039647318505!3d48.56905316137844!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4796c8495e18b2c1%3A0x971a483118e7241f!2sStrasbourg!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sfr!4v1659196020939!5m2!1sen!2sfr" width="300" height="400" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" data-aos="fade-up"></iframe>
                    <!-- <iframe
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d316530.06898113067!2d38.75890546037433!3d51.69843674434513!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x413b2f5ce874e813%3A0x48d94c0efba762bd!2sWoronesch%2C%20Oblast%20Woronesch%2C%20Russland!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1658941426253!5m2!1sde!2sde"
                    width="300" height="200" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
                    referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0" data-aos="fade-left">
   <form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="POST">
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Prénom"
               aria-label="Nom Prénom" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
       </div>
       <!-- Email address input -->
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
           <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
               aria-label="email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-telephone-fill"></i></span>
           <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Téléphone"
               aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
       </div>
       <!-- Message input -->
       <div class="mb-3">
           <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
               placeholder="Decrivez le plus possible votre projet" name="message" required></textarea>
       </div>
       <!-- Form submit button -->
       <div class="d-grid">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="send" type="submit">Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <footer style="background-color: #2c2c2c;">
        <div class="container" style="padding: 5%;">
            <div class="row justify-content-between gx-4 gx-lg-5">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <h6 style="color: white;"> Développeur Informatique Indépendant</h6>

                    <p class="grisclaire">Développeur Web front & back-end & Webdesigner freelance, je suis à votre
                        disposition pour répondre à
                        tout type
                        de projets de création de sites internet, de développement spécifique ou d'applications web.
                    </p>

                    <p class="grisclaire">Passionné par les technologies liées au Web, je mets mes compétences au
                        service de vos besoins dans
                        divers
                        domaines.</p>
                </div>



                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0 " data-aos="fade-left">

                    <h6 style="color: white;"> Mathieu CRÉVOULIN</h6></br>
                    <a class="grisclaire footertext" href="https://goo.gl/maps/XD9CrQDL9WXZWrWV6" style="margin-bottom: 0; text-decoration: none;"> <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"> 45, allée
                            des Grives 83390 Cuers </i></a></br>
                    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=33651289271" class="grisclaire footertext" style="margin-bottom: 0; text-decoration: none;"> <i class="bi bi-whatsapp"></i> (+33)
                        6.15.42.10.45</a>
                    <p class="grisclaire footertext" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
                        contact@mcrevoulin.com </p>
                    <p class="grisclaire footertext" style="margin-bottom: 0;"><i class="bi bi-link"></i>
                        www.mathieu-crevoulin.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </footer>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const $this = $(this);

            // disable submit button
            const $button = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').text('Submit...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            // send message
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'contact.php',
                data: $this.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert("E-mail envoyé avec succès ! Merci pour votre message ! Une réponse vous sera apportée dans les plus brefs délais.");
                     $this[0].reset(); // reset form
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('An error occurred. Please try again')
                },
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    // enable submit button
                    $button.text('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            })
        })
    });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to do the same so that after sending an email there is an alert that appears as in the example I showed (without loading the page or sending to a new page). I tried to create a new page with an alert but I wish its done like in the example I showed. How should I do?

Comment: You have to use AJAX

Comment: @ruleboy21 how i can do this?

Comment: There are many AJAX tutorials online already. Basically you use it to send an asynchronous HTTP request to the server without the browser needing to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using AJAX. Try this

contact.php file

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])){

    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'mymail@mail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'psw';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port = 465;      
    $mail->setFrom('mymail@mail.com');

    $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Projet web';
    $mail->Body = "Message:" . $body . "<br>Phone number: " . $phone . "<br>Name: " . $name . "<br>Mail: " . $email;

    $mail->send();

    // header("Location:  http://127.0.0.1/test2/confirmmail.html#scrollspyHeading7");
    echo 'sent';
    exit;
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0" data-aos="fade-left">
   <form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="POST">
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Prénom"
               aria-label="Nom Prénom" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
       </div>
       <!-- Email address input -->
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
           <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
               aria-label="email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-telephone-fill"></i></span>
           <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Téléphone"
               aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
       </div>
       <!-- Message input -->
       <div class="mb-3">
           <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
               placeholder="Decrivez le plus possible votre projet" name="message" required></textarea>
       </div>
       <!-- Form submit button -->
       <div class="d-grid">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="send" type="submit">Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Add this before the closing body tag. For submitting the form asynchronously

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const $this = $(this);

            // disable submit button
            const $button = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').text('Submit...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            // send message
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'contact.php',
                data: $this.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert("E-mail envoyé avec succès ! Merci pour votre message ! Une réponse vous sera apportée dans les plus brefs délais.");
                     $this[0].reset(); // reset form
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('An error occurred. Please try again')
                },
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    // enable submit button
                    $button.text('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: i have add but this redirect me in page .contact.php where writing sent

Comment: there you have all my code html https://jsfiddle.net/prdv41yc/

Comment: @xajetin your code works perfectly. Just add the jquery I provided before the closing body tag

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/9y32gvo7/

Comment: @xajetin did https://jsfiddle.net/9y32gvo7/ help?

Comment: when i click in submit show alert but mail don't send